# Java class Thread Safe methods, for exam certification 1Z0-851

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am studing for 1Z0-851 Oracla Java SE 1.6 Certification and I saw this question:

[image: question 4]

Can anybody explain me this answer?

And say whether I am correct when I think this way: 
if `doThings()` is static only one access can be made by time despite of when a method is not `static` once each `TestSeven` object would access doThings at the same time modifying the x value inconsistently.

Am I correct on thinking this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's it. At the moment, if you create two instances of `TestSeven` and call their `doThings` method from 2 different threads, you have no guarantee that `x` will be incremented twice. For example, the following execution is legal (T1 and T2 are the two threads):

```
T1: current = x //0
T2: current = x //0
T1: current++; // 1
T2: current++; // 1
T1: x = current; // 1
T2: x = current; // 1
```

So you have called the method twice but x has been incremented only once.

If you make the method static, only one thread will be able to execute it at a given moment, even if you create many instances.

Comment: good! thats what I thought.. I could do a `synchronized(TestSeven.class) {}` instead of making this method static also??

Comment: Correct, you could use a synchronized block where the lock is the class (or another arbitrary static field).

Comment: @thiagoh yes it would achieve the same: you could use any static object as a lock (TestSeven.class is one possibility).

Answer (score 2):

It's not thread-safe because *x* scope is "static", ie all classes instance can access it, and the *doThings* methods isn't. So it's synchronized only on the class instance.

Therefore, there can be two classes instance accessing *x* in the same time despite the synchronized keyword.

Making the method static would ensure it to be called only once at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The `doThings()` method is an instance method and is reading and writing to a static variable `x`. By making `doThings()` static, it will be synchronized across all instances (intrinsic lock on the class, rather than on the instance). In other words, as it currently stands, the method can be invoked simultaneously by multiple threads, whereas making it static would prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

If x is not marked static then will the class be thread-safe?